# Create Sequence Date with number in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I wanted to create a sequence for the id of the directDebit class.
For it, I want the day in the format (dd_mm_yy) followed by a number that indicates the number that was created in the day.

```
// Class in java
@Entity
public class DirectDebit implements Serializable {

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "directDebit_generator")initialValue=1, allocationSize=50)
@Id
private String id;

...
}

-- create sequence in mysql
CREATE SEQUENCE directDebit_generator
    START WITH 1
    MAXVALUE 99999999
    MINVALUE 1
    NOCYCLE
    NOCACHE
    NOORDER;

-- Format date in mysql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '%d_%m_%Y');


//Examples of id today
10_12_2016_1
10_12_2016_2
10_12_2016_3
...

//Examples of id yesterday
09_12_2016_1
09_12_2016_2
...
```

Do you understand what I want?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own `org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator`. Into `generate(...)` can call you your SELECT and build the identifier. The code is only a idea, not for copy&paster.

```
public class DirectDebitSequenceGenerator
    extends SequenceGenerator
{
    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object obj)
    {
        // Your code
    }
}
```

Entity:

```
public class Entity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = "GenerationType.SEQUENCE", generator = "generator")
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "...DirectDebitSequenceGenerator")
private String id;

...

}
```

Comment: That is, I put Display Date.format (LocalDateTime.now (), "dd_MM_YY");
And the number How to increase.

Comment: Write a custom generator is very hard. Here are 2 exmaples https://vladmihalcea.com/2016/06/13/how-to-implement-a-custom-string-based-sequence-identifier-generator-with-hibernate/ http://blog.anorakgirl.co.uk/2009/01/custom-hibernate-sequence-generator-for-id-field/